# Erro no tab-content do bootstrap. Mostra elementos empilhados na alternância de abas

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-3, front-end

Boa tarde. Estamos desenvolvendo um site para um grupo de pesquisa do mestrado, sou bolsista, do curso de sistemas de informação, com pouca experiência em programação web, quem puder ajudar, por bondade!
Usando o nav-tabs e tab-content do bootstrap, quando troca as abas, o conteúdo da aba seguindo fica abaixo do conteúdo da aba anterior, como se os outros elementos estivessem empilhados sob o novo elemento.

O conteúdo das tab-content está sendo criado dinamicamente pela variável de contexto da views.py do django.

Segue o código:

```
<!-- MOSTRA AS ABAS DE PROJETOS EM ANDAMENTO E CONCLUÍDO -->
<div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8" style="display:none;"  id="abas_projetos"><!--cria 2 abas de navegação-->
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" >
        <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#aba_projetos_em_andamento" onclick="alternar_abas()">
            Projetos Em Andamento</a>
        </li>

        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#aba_projetos_concluidos" onclick="alternar_abas()">
            Projetos Concluídos</a>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <div id="aba_projetos_em_andamento" class="tab-pane fade active in" > <!--cria o conteudo da aba de projetos concluidos -->

        {% for pesquisa in pesquisas_andamento.all %}

        <div class="tab-content" class="tabContent_projetos_em_andamento">
            <h4>
                <a href="#{{ pesquisa.id }}" data-toggle="collapse">
                    {{ pesquisa.titulo }}
                </a>
            </h4>
            <div id="{{ pesquisa.id}}" class="collapse">
                <strong>Ementa:</strong> {{ pesquisa.ementa }}
                <a href=" url app_name:page_name.html "> + info </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}


    </div>

    <div id="aba_projetos_concluidos" class="tab-pane fade" > <!--cria o conteudo da aba de projetos concluidos -->
        {% for pesquisa in pesquisas_concluidas.all %}
            <div class="tab-content" class="tabContent_projetos_concluidos">
                <h4>
                    <a href="#{{ pesquisa.id}}" data-toggle="collapse">
                        {{ pesquisa.titulo }}
                    </a>
                </h4>
                <div id=" {{ pesquisa.id }} " class="collapse">
                    <strong>Ementa:</strong> {{ pesquisa.ementa }}
                </div>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}

    </div>
</div>   <!-- FECHA A DIV DAS ABAS DOS PROJETOS -->
```

O print da página:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: mostrando como o layout é desenhado na tela]

Comment: Cara acredito que seu problema é com relação ao "fade" entre um conteúdo e outro. Não sei a dinâmica nem o CSS que vc usou, mas se vc está usando visibility ou opacity 0 pode ser que esse erro acontece, vc precisa setar `display:none` no conteúdo da primeira Aba quando for mostrar o conteúdo da segunda aba.

Comment: obrigado hugocsl tiver que resolver usando a propriedade display mesmo, mas primeiro foi necessário 'setar' ela explicitamente na declaração da tag! Só assim que foi possível manipular essa propriedade, do contrário ela fica 'undefined'.

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde, agradeço o apoio. Consegui resolver.
**Foi necessário colocar explicitamente a propriedade display nos 'tab-content'**. style="display:block;". Acho que essa propriedade não é configurada por padrão. Já vi outros comentários sobre isso! Estava tentando pegar a propriedade com javascript, mas ela estava vindo em branco.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" >
        <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#aba_projetos_em_andamento" onclick="alternar_abas()">
            Projetos Em Andamento</a>
        </li>

        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#aba_projetos_concluidos" onclick="alternar_abas()">
            Projetos Concluídos</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
<div class="tab-content" id="tabContent_projetos_em_andamento"
                style="display:block;">
div class="tab-content" id="tabContent_projetos_concluidos"
                style="display:none;">
```

Chamando a função, ele compara o display:

```
function alternar_abas(){
        var tab_content_projetos_em_andamento = document.getElementById("tabContent_projetos_em_andamento")
        var tab_content_projetos_concluidos = document.getElementById("tabContent_projetos_concluidos")
        console.log("antes de alternar display´s")
        console.log("tab_content_projetos_em_andamento.style.display : " + tab_content_projetos_em_andamento.style.display)
        console.log("tab_content_projetos_concluidos.style.display : " + tab_content_projetos_concluidos.style.display)

        if (tab_content_projetos_em_andamento.style.display == 'block'){
            tab_content_projetos_em_andamento.style.display = 'none'
            tab_content_projetos_concluidos.style.display = 'block'
        } else {
            tab_content_projetos_em_andamento.style.display = 'block'
            tab_content_projetos_concluidos.style.display = 'none'
        }

        console.log("depois de alternar display´s")
        console.log("tab_content_projetos_em_andamento.style.display : " + tab_content_projetos_em_andamento.style.display)
        console.log("tab_content_projetos_concluidos.style.display : " + tab_content_projetos_concluidos.style.display)
    }
```

Agora está mostrando no começo certo
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora ele está tirando o 'height'(altura) dos objetos. Do contrário, vai empilhando. 
Pelo que pesquisei não achei muitos posts falando sobre essa situação (do empilhamento do conteúdos dos tab-pane´s)...